# AdminBSB - how to make modal forms wider

Tags: html, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using [AdminBSB](https://github.com/gurayyarar/AdminBSBMaterialDesign) with the MVC Core + jQuery template.  I was wondering if the width of the modal forms can be easily customised without breaking other styles?

I'd love to just make them a little wider.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the style with `width` and `height` like below.

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 80%;height: 88%;">
```

Or you can see demo [modal-sm](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal_sm&stacked=h) or [modal-lg](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal_lg&stacked=h) also.

Answer (score 1):

it's based on Bootstrap 3.X 
so in Bootstrap Modal component size can be small, medium or large.

Small Modal

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
```

Large Modal

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
```

See the related doc
https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.5/docs/javascript/#modals-sizes